# My sentinel controlled while loop is not working

Tags: java

I can't get the while loop to work.  The Program prompt user whether (s)he wants to continue, enter 0 toquit or any other integer to continue. If the user wants to c
ontinue, the program will loop back to themenu, otherwise, it will exit. Thus, you should have a sentinel-controlled loop that will end when a 0 is entered

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AdoptAPet
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {  
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int gender = 0;

    double costAdoption = 0.0;
    double costGenderSelect = 0.0;
    double costAnyGender = 0.0;
    double costProcessing = 0.0;
    double total = 0.0;
    int genderCounter = 0;

    System.out.println("Choose from the following options: 1 for male, 2 for female, 3 for any");

     while(gender != 0);//begin sentinel controlled while loop
    {
    System.out.print("Please choose the gender of the cat you wish to purchase:");
    gender = input.nextInt();

   if(gender < 0)
   {
    System.out.println("INVALID CHOICE! ");

    System.out.print("enter 0 to quit: 0 or enter any other nunber to continue:");
    gender = input.nextInt();
   }

    if(gender == 1)
    { 
    costAdoption = 9.50;
    costAdoption += costProcessing + 2.00;
    total += costAdoption;

    System.out.printf("Your Choice is: " );
    System.out.printf("male and the total is $%.2f", total);
    }

    if(gender == 2)
    {
    costGenderSelect = 11.50;
    costGenderSelect += costProcessing + 2.00;
    total += costGenderSelect;

    System.out.printf("Your Choice is: " );
    System.out.printf("female and the total is $%.2f", total);
    }

    if(gender == 3)
    {
    costAnyGender = 9.50;
    costAnyGender += costProcessing + 2.00;
    total += costAnyGender;

    System.out.printf("Your Choice is: " );
    System.out.printf("Any gender and the total is $%.2f", total);
    }

    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is responsible:

```
while(gender != 0);//begin sentinel controlled while loop
```

Look closely. There is a semi-colon at the end - that is the entire statement. The {} block that follows does not belong to the loop (and is executed exactly once).

Try dropping the ; from the end - we've fixed our while loop, but now the {} loop body doesn't execute at all. This is because gender is initialized with a value of 0. So to get our loop to execute at least once we need to either initialize gender to something else, or use a do-while loop.

Here is the modified code using a do-while.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AdoptAPet
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {  
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      int gender = 0;

      double costAdoption = 0.0;
      double costGenderSelect = 0.0;
      double costAnyGender = 0.0;
      double costProcessing = 0.0;
      double total = 0.0;
      int genderCounter = 0;

      System.out.println("Choose from the following options: 1 for male, 2 for female, 3 for any");

      do   //begin sentinel controlled while loop
      {
         System.out.print("Please choose the gender of the cat you wish to purchase:");
         gender = input.nextInt();

         if(gender < 0)
         {
            System.out.println("INVALID CHOICE! ");

            System.out.print("enter 0 to quit: 0 or enter any other nunber to continue:");
            gender = input.nextInt();
         }

         if (gender == 1)
         { 
            costAdoption = 9.50;
            costAdoption += costProcessing + 2.00;
            total += costAdoption; 

            System.out.printf("Your Choice is: " );
            System.out.printf("male and the total is $%.2f", total);
         }

         if (gender == 2)
         {
            costGenderSelect = 11.50;
            costGenderSelect += costProcessing + 2.00;
            total += costGenderSelect;

            System.out.printf("Your Choice is: " );
            System.out.printf("female and the total is $%.2f", total);
         }

         if (gender == 3)
         {
            costAnyGender = 9.50;
            costAnyGender += costProcessing + 2.00;
            total += costAnyGender;

            System.out.printf("Your Choice is: " );
            System.out.printf("Any gender and the total is $%.2f", total);
         }

      } while(gender != 0);   //end sentinel controlled while loop
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
while(gender != 0);//<-- remove the semi colon,loop gets terminated by it
```

Also declare gender as:

```
int gender = -1;//<-- this will cause the loop to start
```